# firestore delete a document's subcollection not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Seriously stumped on this one. I am trying to delete a nested record inside of the collection "kids".

"todaysEvents" is a map (inside of the kid's collection) and I am targeting the deletion of one of the key/value pairs (the event.id). I have given all permissions and when I run it, it returns that the document was successfully deleted yet it actually has not been deleted as i can still see it in the DB. Is there something special with maps that I need to do before deleting? I feel like this should work smoothly...

```
FIRESTORE.db
    .collection("kids")
    .doc(event.kidId)
    .collection("todaysEvents")
    .doc(event.id)
    .delete()
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!", data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Please include you're database structure (either as text or a image) and values for `id` and `kidId`.

Comment: I don't follow your use of terminology.  From the code, it looks like `todaysEvents` is a subcollection and not a "map".  And it looks like you are trying to delete a document within that subcollection whose value is `event.id`.  So when you say "still see it in the DB" -- what is "it" that you are seeing?  A document? An entry in a map (and if so...in what document does that map live?).  Firestore is a Document Store Database.  You read and write DOCUMENTS, and you organize them in collections/subcollections.  So, are you trying to delete a DOCUMENT?

Comment: @samthecodingman see updated post with image of the DB

Comment: @GregFenton `todaysEvents` is a map inside of the subcollection. When I say it still exists in the database, I am talking about the event that I want to delete (event.id) is still persisting in the database. I don't want to delete the entire Kids document, rather the sub document inside of the kid's document. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is a Document Store Database.  The operations available to you are to find/read, create, update and delete individual and ENTIRE documents (think: JSON objects) at a time.

There is no API to delete just a field within an existing document.  Rather, you need to read the document (the JSON object), modify the object (e.g. delete an element out of the document), and then write the document back to Firestore.

So in your example you would do something like (pseudo-code below):

```js
const removeEventId = async (kidId, todayEventsId) => {
  try {
    // fetch the "kids" document
    let docRef = FIRESTORE.db.collection("kids").doc(kidId);
    let docSnap = await docRef.get();
    let docData = docSnap.data();

    // remove the element that we no longer want in the document
    delete docData.todaysEvents[todaysEventId];

    // update the document in Firestore
    await docRef.update(docData);
    console.log(`Document updated with ${todaysEventId} removed!`, docData);
  } catch (ex) {
      console.error(`EXCEPTION while removing ${todaysEventId}:`, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: ah I didn't know this, that make sense. thank you!

Comment: Deleting particular fields in a document is possible, see the answer I posted for details.

Answer (score 1):

In [@GregFenton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229326/greg-fenton) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591796/3068190), they incorrectly stated:

> There is no API to delete just a field within an existing document

Firestore supports [updates using "field transforms"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) which are provided by the [`FieldValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) class. This class creates sentinel values that are understood by the Firestore API to mean "take this special action" like inserting an element into an array, incrementing a number, or inserting the time the server processed the request. To delete an existing field in a document, you would use the sentinel created by [`FieldValue.delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-delete).

To delete a field called `fieldName` from an existing document, you can use the sentinel with the [`DocumentReference#update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method, in either of these formats:

```js
docRef.update({
  [fieldName]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
// or
docRef.update(fieldName, firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete())
```

Applying this to the code from [@GregFenton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229326/greg-fenton) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591796/3068190), gives:

```js
const removeEventId = async (kidId, todayEventsId) => {
  if (!todayEventsId) {
    throw new TypeError("todayEventsId must not be falsy");
  }

  // get a reference to the kid's document
  const docRef = FIRESTORE.db.collection("kids").doc(kidId);

  // update the document in Firestore
  return docRef.update(
    `todaysEvents.${todaysEventId}`,
    firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
  );
}
```

Note here, that I removed the log messages from the function itself as you should handle errors wherever you call the code from instead. This prevents the problem where errors are improperly handled & reported.

Example Usage:

```js
try {
  await removeEventId(kidId, todaysEventId);
  console.log(`Removed event #${todaysEventId} from kid #${kidId}!`);
} catch (ex) {
  console.error(`EXCEPTION while removing ${todaysEventId}:`, ex);
}
```

If you do want to "sink" these errors and make the event removal optional, you should at least return back whether the operation was successful or not.

```js
const removeEventId = async (kidId, todayEventsId) => {
  try {
    if (!todayEventsId) {
      throw new TypeError("todayEventsId must not be falsy");
    }

    // get a reference to the kid's document
    const docRef = FIRESTORE.db.collection("kids").doc(kidId);

    // update the document in Firestore
    return docRef.update(
      `todaysEvents.${todaysEventId}`,
      firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
    );

    console.log(`Removed event #${todaysEventId} from kid #${kidId}!`);
    return true;
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(`EXCEPTION while removing ${todaysEventId}:`, ex);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Example Usage:

```js
const eventWasRemoved = await removeEventId(kidId, todaysEventId);
if (!eventWasRemoved) {
  alert('Failed to remove that event!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and verify you are a good id

```
FIRESTORE.db
.collection("kids")
.doc(event.kidId)
.collection("todaysEvents")
.doc(event.id).get().subscribe(data => {
      data.ref.delete().then(() => {
      console.log('success')
    }, error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
  });
```